# writing inline footnotes for html to mobi conversion using calibre

Tags: calibre, mobi, html, footnotes

I'm generating html code that I convert to `.mobi` format using Calibre.  I have implemented endnotes with backlinks as follows:

text.html:

```
this is some text <a id="footnote1" href='footnotes/1.html'>[1]</a>
```

footnotes/1.html:

```
Here is a footnote <a href="text.html#footnote1>[..]</a>
```

For Calibre's HTML to `.mobi` conversion, **what HTML code should I write to use in-line footnotes instead of endnotes?**

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason every footnote is in its own separate file? Why not have all footnotes in a single file and link to the footnote like this: `href='fnfile.html#fn1'`?

Comment: i'll consider it thanks.  do you know how to display inline footnotes?

Comment: Sorry I do not use Calibre. I write in MultiMarkdown and convert that to an EPUB.

Comment: can you link a guide?

Comment: This is a real quick inline footnote how-to. http://pastebin.com/CvNxSJer. Once you click on the footnote in the text, it will take you to the footnote itself. Hit the browser BACK button to go back to the actual text you were reading.

Comment: Thanks, but mine already does that.  I'm looking for the standard Kindle-style footnote experience.

Comment: Hi @WalrustheCat, I have the same problem, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. To make the inline footnote works, must put the footnotes in the "Footnotes" section. Here is the example:

I have the file: "HDN is the best.html"

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HDN is the best</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Best of HDN</h1>
<p><sup><a id='fs-1' href='#ft-1'>[1]</a></sup> HDN is the best</p>
<p><sup><a id='fs-2' href='#ft-2'>[2]</a></sup> HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>
<p>HDN is the best</p>

<h1>Footnotes</h1><br>
<sup><a id='ft-1' href='#fs-1'>[1]</a></sup> It's true.<br>
<sup><a id='ft-2' href='#fs-2'>[2]</a></sup> It's double true.<br>

</body>
</html>
```

There, just convert the file "HDN is the best.html" and see for yourself.

Now here is the tip: when you convert this file "HDN is the best.html" to mobi file, Calibre may count footnotes as chapters, that'd be a mess for your table of content. So you need to prevent Calibre from doing this by using the cmd (using the option `--toc-threshold 0`) instead of using UI, here is the cmd:

```
ebook-convert.exe "E:\temp\TempMisc\HDN is the best.html" "E:\temp\TempMisc\HDN is the best.mobi" --toc-threshold 0
```

location of ebook-convert.exe is `.\[Your installed Calibre folder]\Calibre\ebook-convert.exe`

Note: this tested and work on my Kindle Paperwhite (second generation), but doesn't work on Kindle app for my iPhone. But it's good enough for me because I read mainly on Kindle Paperwhite.

Comment: For further discussion, go to: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=333269